# MYSQL query not returning expected result after removing stop words

Tags: php, mysql, stop-words

I am trying to remove stop words from my local system having mysql version 5.5.38 . I searched for `ft_stopword_file` in */etc/mysql/my.cnf* and couldn't find it. So I added the line

```
ft_stopword_file = ""
```

in that file and restarted the mysql server.
Then repaired the indexes using

```
 REPAIR TABLE articles QUICK
```

I am using a table named *articles* which have structure like :

```
 mysql> CREATE TABLE articles (
        id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        title VARCHAR(200),
        body TEXT,
        FULLTEXT (title,body)
      ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

 mysql> INSERT INTO articles (title,body) VALUES
      ('MySQL Tutorial','DBMS stands for DataBase ...'),
      ('Testing','Anything happened ...'),
      ('Optimizing MySQL','In this tutorial we will show ...'),
      ('1001 MySQL Tricks','1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ...'),
      ('MySQL vs. YourSQL','In the following database comparison ...'),
      ('MySQL Security','When configured properly, MySQL ...');
```

I tried the FULLTEXT SEARCH query :

```
 SELECT * FROM articles  WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('anything');
```

which returned 0 records even though there is one record with that word in articles table. Also I read from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html that stop words are listed in *storage/myisam/ft_static.c*, but I can't find out this folder in my LAMP.

Can anyone please help me to find out the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: execute following statement and check what is output "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_stopword_file';"

Comment: Not sure about the structure here (never seen SQL like this before...), but would you not need to do something such as: ` SELECT * FROM articles  WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('anything', 'anything'); `

Comment: It is returning (built-in) as value

Comment: Stop word indexing is only used with MyISAM tables and fields with FULLTEXT indexing. Are your tables MyISAM?

Comment: @vivoconunxino..Yes, it is.